# How to grant github.token permissions to access organization packages?

Tags: github, github-actions

When you run a GitHub workflow, you can grant the `github.token` permissions to access packages and contents. But in an organization, that permissions are scoped to your private repository and do not have access to any organization resources. This is true even if you create a pull request to the organization repository.

In my organization, our dotnet projects use our private Nuget packages, and my PR won't build because it can not pull those private packages. We have to create a *PAT* and save it in the *secret*, then refer to that secret in the GitHub workflow. This creates extra administration work to maintain those PAT.

Is it possible to grant the `github.token` permission to access organization packages?

Comment: As of right now, the `github.token` cannot be given organization-scoped permissions. The scope is relatively limited and you will need to use a PAT and add it as a repository secret. See [Granting Additional Permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#granting-additional-permissions).

Comment: yeah, that's what we are doing right now. it sucks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credit to Ed

> As of right now, the github.token cannot be given organization-scoped permissions. The scope is relatively limited and you will need to use a PAT and add it as a repository secret. [See Granting Additional Permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#granting-additional-permissions).